# Creating a Panel Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks somewhat like this. There are 100,000 rows where each row has the name of a person and the start and end date of a trip they took.

The trips of the different travelers may overlap.

[image]

What I want to do is create a dataframe that stores their travel history as a time series where if they stayed home on a date, the value is zero and if they were travelling on a date the value is 1. So something like this:

[image]

Here is what I have done so far and it seems to work. I have a feeling that what I am doing may not be efficient and may not be best practice since I am populating a dataframe inside a loop. I'd appreciate any help in making my code better and me learning new stuff in the process. MWE below. Thanks.

First, I create the raw data.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

my_dict = {'Name': ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B"], 'Start Date': ['1/1/2019', '4/5/2019', '7/7/2019', '1/1/2019', '12/1/2019'], 'End Date': ['1/6/2019', '4/20/2019', '7/9/2019', '1/17/2019', '12/10/2019']}
df_raw = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict)
df_raw['Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_raw['Start Date'], infer_datetime_format=True) 
df_raw['End Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_raw['End Date'], infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Then I create a dataframe filled with zeros with appropriate index and column names

```
date_range2 = pd.date_range(start=df_raw['Start Date'].min(), end=df_raw['End Date'].max())
columns2 = df_raw['Name'].unique()

df_panel2 = pd.DataFrame(index=date_range2, columns=columns2)
df_panel2 = df_panel2.fillna(0)
```

Then I loop through my original dataframe and populate the new dataframe wherever needed

```
for index, row in df_raw.iterrows():
    for date in pd.date_range(start=row['Start Date'], end=row['End Date']):
        df_panel2.loc[date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'),row['Name']] = 1
```

Comment: why is 2019-01-07 0 for both A and B? B was on a trip that started from 2019-01-01 and ended 2019-01-17

Comment: Shouldn't 2019-01-01 have 1s both both A and B ? Because the dates overlap.

Comment: Oops. Sorry I didn't update the second picture after I changed the raw data. Apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with `pd.IntervalIndex.` along with `pd.get_dummies` after creating the `date_range2`

```
idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df_raw['Start Date'],
                                   df_raw['End Date'],closed='both')

out = pd.get_dummies(df_raw.set_index(idx)['Name'].reindex(date_range2))
```

---

```
print(out.head(15))

            A  B
2019-01-01  1  0
2019-01-02  1  0
2019-01-03  1  0
2019-01-04  1  0
2019-01-05  1  0
2019-01-06  1  0
2019-01-07  0  0
2019-01-08  0  1
2019-01-09  0  1
2019-01-10  0  1
2019-01-11  0  0
2019-01-12  0  0
2019-01-13  0  0
2019-01-14  0  0
2019-01-15  0  0
```

Comment: There is a problem when the travelers have the same dates for some of their trips. I am getting the error "cannot reindex from a duplicate axis" . Would you know how to get around it? I'll modify the data in the original question to reflect that. Thx

Comment: @Amatya Try `s = df_raw.set_index(idx)['Name']` and then `out = pd.get_dummies(s.groupby(s).apply(lambda x: x.reindex(date_range2))).max(level=1)`

Comment: Wow!! Nicely done!! :) I learned a bunch of stuff. Thank you!

Comment: In my real data, I have someone going on trip 1 from say Jan-1-2019 to Jan-5-2019 and then immediately a second trip from Jan-5-2019 to say Jan-7-2019. Since we're taking interval index as closed intervals, I am getting the "cannot reindex from duplicate axis" error again. I guess one way to solve this would be to merge the intersecting index intervals. I am trying to implement this, parallelly I wanted to ask if you have any thoughts on this. Thanks

Comment: @Amatya Need to try this out. It might also need a totally different approach..!! Meanwhile would you be able to post a new question having this question covered in the dataset? I can take a look later in the day, you would also get fresh sets of eyes :)